# C++ - Can you overload a function with different parameters but define it only once?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm a beginner in c++ and I'm trying to make a simple command line game. I have three classes:

```
class DynamicEntity : public Entity { // Entity class has only int x, y variables and getters/setters
    protected:
        enum direction {RIGHT = 77, LEFT = 75, UP = 72, DOWN = 80};
    public:
        posWrap getNextPos(); // Returns the xy coordinates of the entity's next position in a struct called posWrap
};

class Player : public DynamicEntity {
    private:
        int wishdir;
    public:
        int ammoCount = 0;
        posWrap getNextPos(); // Same concept as above, but takes input
};

class CollisionHandler {
    public:
        static char checkCollisions(DynamicEntity& dEntity); // Checks the next position of the entity for collisions and returns what it would collide with
        static char checkCollisions(Player& player); 

};
```

You see, I have overloaded the `checkCollisions` method. And defined the `DynamicEntity` version as such:

```
char CollisionHandler::checkCollisions(DynamicEntity& dEntity) {
    int x = dEntity.getNextPos().x;
    int y = dEntity.getNextPos().y;

    return readChar(x, y);
}
```

The implementation of the `getNextPos` functions are different for `Player` and `DynamicEntity`, as the first one takes an input from the player while the latter gets its orders from somewhere else in the program.
I want to know if it is possible to pass in a `Player` class to `checkCollisions` and inside the method, use the `Player` version of `getNextPos`, without explicitly writing another definition of `checkCollisions`. I thought it would be possible since `Player` is a child of `DynamicEntity`. Or am I asking too much of the compiler?

Let me know if you have any other suggestions, criticism or a better way to do this stuff. I am trying to learn more in-depth about these topics. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I want to know if it is possible to pass in a `Player` class to `checkCollisions`" - have you tried actually doing this?

Comment: Kind-of obvious answer is to use a virtual function, so I'm puzzled by your question. In any case, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if it is possible to pass in a Player class to checkCollisions and inside the method, use the Player version of getNextPos, without explicitly writing another definition of checkCollisions.

You seem to misunderstand how overloading and virtual dispatch works. This function

```
static char checkCollisions(DynamicEntity& dEntity);
```

can be called with a `Player`. You do not need the other overload. Though to make it work as expected you should declare `getNextPos()` as virtual, such that when `checkCollisions(DynamicEntity&)` is called with a `Player&` it will call `Player::getNextPos()`:

```
class DynamicEntity {
    public:
        virtual posWrap getNextPos();
      //^^
        virtual ~DynamicEntity(){} // polymorphic types need a virtual destructor
};

class Player : public DynamicEntity {
        posWrap getNextPos() override; // <- add override to help with typos               
};

class CollisionHandler {
    public:
        static char checkCollisions(DynamicEntity& dEntity);    
};
```

PS:

> Can you overload a function with different parameters but define it only once?

No. You cannot call a function that has no definition. If you actually try it you would get a linker error.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to make `DynamicEntiry::getNextPos` a virtual function and override it in `Player`

```
class DynamicEntity : public Entity { // Entity class has only int x, y variables and getters/setters
    protected:
        enum direction {RIGHT = 77, LEFT = 75, UP = 72, DOWN = 80};
    public:
        virtual posWrap getNextPos(); // virtual keyword is mandotary here. Allow sub-class to override it.
};

class Player : public DynamicEntity {
    private:
        int wishdir;
    public:
        int ammoCount = 0;
        virtual posWrap getNextPos() override; // the virtual keyword here is optional. The override keyword makes sure you are overriding.
};

class CollisionHandler {
    public:
        static char checkCollisions(DynamicEntity& dEntity);

};
```

You can of course pass a `Player` object to `checkCollisions`

```
Player player;
CollisionHandler::checkCollisions(player);
```

If you are new to virtual function, you may want to read some books or articles: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/

You may also be interested in the double dispatching technique, which is a more complicated but also more power design: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C++